# Prevent events on transparent layout

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a transparent layout (see below) which I programmatically inflate and add over an exiting layout. This is working fine, but I can still scroll and use buttons below the black 0.3 alpha area.

How can I prevent this and build a "real" modal layout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your view intercept touch and click event.

Add `android:clickable="true"` to your black relative layout.
If it doesn't work,  you need to add `focusableInTouchMode` to true and `focusable` to true as well.